# How to test index performance & comparision testing with my own newly created indexing code?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, testing, indexing

I have developed one index code i.e, some different algo. for indexing in Database (particularly for Relational Database System) & I want to perform comparison testing with other indexing technique used such as B-Tree,B+Tree,Hashing etc. in various database.

How can I do such testing & performance analysis? I am looking forward to do this with MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL,MongoDB & some other.

I searched on Google but not get any related information about, so that I can put my first step down.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you get e.g. SQL Server or Oracle to use your method of indexing? As far as I know you can't create new types of index for these DBMS's: how indexes are implemented are internal to these products and not available to users. Or are you doing something else?

Comment: Thanks for reply @simonatrcl.
Yes definitely I want to apply my own code of indexing(specifically for primary indexing) in any of those DBMS(MySQL, MsSQL, Oracle etc) and want to compare & perform analysis of my own algo(code) with what their database engine are using (B-Tree, R-Tree, Hashing).
Any ideas? Pls reply soon.

Comment: I really don't think it's possible. There's no way of getting your code to be run by SQLServer or Oracle instead of its own. (SQLServer lets you upload .NET code, but I don't think you can use that to do what you want.) However, this http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2009/04/18/how-important-is-extensibility-for-sql-server.aspx might be of interest. One of the comments notes that Postgres has an extensibility point which sounds like what you want. The second comments says why extending the DBMS itself is a bad idea. Good luck, anyway!

Comment: Really? isn't this possible? I am quite sure that there must be some tool or method so that we can see our self how hashing is good then B-tree, B+tree in some cases. BTW thanks for your reply..hoping some how I can get know to how do this things.

Comment: As I said, I think your best approach is to look at the Postgres extensibility point mentioned in that comment. I am pretty sure that you can't do this in SQLServer or Oracle.